# interp1 on complex numbers in Scilab?

Tags: interpolation, complex-numbers, scilab

Does anyone know how can i perform interpolation on complex numbers in Scilab?
We can do this in Matlab using "interp1" with a complex numbers vector as 2nd input, but not in Scilab.

thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, on my Scilab (5.5.2), "interp1" just strips the imaginary part.

Try replacing:

```
res = interp1(x,y,xx)
```

by:

```
c = size(y)*[0;1]
D = eye(c,c)
res = interp1(x,[real(y),imag(y)],xx)*[D;%i*D]
```

It should work with any dimensions for y. You can make it a one liner if you want but it will be less readable.

or by (simpler but maybe slower):

```
res = interp1(x,real(y),xx) + %i * interp1(x,imag(y),xx)
```